# How to find last value from Ms Sql

Tags: sql-server, query

I have an example table like this:

| ID | UserId | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 00009 | Jomy |
| 2 | 00012 | Tomy |
| 3 | 00012 | Tomy |
| 4 | 00012 | Tomy |
| 5 | 00009 | Jomy |

I want to get the last value of `UserId = 00012`, (`UserId` from `ID` number `4`). I have tried several queries like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE UserId = 00012 
ORDER BY UserId DESC
```

But it didn't work. Can you guys help me to find the correct query?

Comment: You need to use the correct column in your `ORDER BY` clause - `... ORDER BY Id DESC`. One additional option is using `ROW_NUMBER()` with appropriate `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

Comment: yes thank you i have find the query how get that, i add another column (addtime) and change ORDER BY UserId to be ORDER BY addtime thank youuuu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have find the answer base on Zhorov answer i put the query bellow

> SELECT TOP 1 ApiType FROM dbo.ApiUserInfo Where UserId=@UserId ORDER
> BY AddTime DESC